# Scala: no corresponding Java Class found

Tags: java, mongodb, scala

While Compiling an Scala 2.10 Project, I got an error I cannot even understand

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to MongoPersistable.this.type found
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.typeToJavaClass(JavaMirrors.scala:1218) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:202) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:65) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.0.jar:na]
...
```

How is this even possible to get such a error message if the code got well in eclipse in first place?

Following line of Code produces this error:

```
trait MongoPersistable {

    def save() {
        val dao : MongoDAO[MongoPersistable.this.type]  = MongoDAO[this.type];
....
```

I would upload more code if I know where to search